# Two strings are equal but wont work on if statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement, string-comparison

```
    System.out.println(characters.get(selected).getName());
    // The name printed is "Mario" But the if statement will not
   // work as though the two strings are diffrent but they are the same.
    if(characters.get(selected).getName() == "Mario"){
        playSound("sounds/clickmario.wav");
    }
```

Comparing two strings and when I debug the comparison is "Mario" to "Mario" so the if statement should be true but its false because nothing inside the if statement is being read. Why is this happening? I have tried assigning this .getname to a tempString and comparing it but still when they are the same string the statement results as false. Please help

Answer (score 3):

You have to use .equals() for string comparison in java

```
if(characters.get(selected).getName().equals("Mario")){
    playSound("sounds/clickmario.wav");
}
```

Comment: == only works on simple primatives. You need to use .equals to compare the String objects to one another. This is correct.

Answer (score 1):

[Refer this for String comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).
and
for basics of String refer [this](http://kishangajjar.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/unit-5-prog-1-introduction-and-basics-of-string/).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if (stra === strb)
```

it should work in javascript, for java

```
if (stra.equals(strb))
```

Then it should work too